# For vectors $v$, $x$, why does $v^{T}x$ = $v \cdot x$

Tags: matrices, vectors

Let $x = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ and $v = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n)$. Shouldn't $v^{T}x$ yield another matrix? I get that it's scalar since the product is a 1 x 1 matrix, but why can we just treat it as the sum $\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n?$

Comment: Write down the matrix $v^Tx$. What is it?

Comment: We can do this out of convenience and [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation).  What truly happens is $v\cdot x=g(v^Tx)$ where $g$ is the function that simply returns the sole entry of the $1\times 1$ matrix $v^Tx$.  Technically $v\cdot x$ (*or rather written $\langle v,x\rangle$*) is an inner product and will always return a scalar number.  Because it is cumbersome to mention (*or even name*) the function $g$, people often leave that out in the identity you show.

Comment: (α1x1+α2x2+...+αnxn)

Comment: Thank you @JMoravitz. That clarifies a lot.

Comment: If $v$ and $x$ are as in your question, that is, both vectors of size $1\times n$ (often called line vectors) then indeed $v^Tx$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is $v_ix_j$, while $vx^T=xv^T=\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n$ is a matrix of size $1\times1$, aka a number. If $v$ and $x$ were column vectors then $v^Tx$ would be the scalar product $\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n$ and $vx^T$ and $xv^T$ would be $n\times n$ matrices.